# SQL Server - CASE FN(str) WHEN x THEN y ELSE keep original value without repeating the functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm wondering whether a variable exists within a case statement that you can use to refer back to the value that was passed in.

For instance, if you have a table like this:

```
Department
shipping
receiving
hr
```

And want this output:

```
Shipping
Receiving 
HR
```

Here's a query that does it:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (dept VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('shipping'), ('receiving'), ('hr')
SELECT 
    CASE UPPER(SUBSTRING(dept, 1, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(dept, 2, LEN(dept) - 1)) 
        WHEN 'Hr' THEN 'HR' 
    ELSE UPPER(SUBSTRING(dept, 1, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(dept, 2, LEN(dept) - 1))
    END
FROM @table
```

Is there a way to do it without repeating all the functions in the else statement? In the ELSE, I just want it to return the original value I passed into the case statement. I'm looking for some built-in variable for the original value, conceptually like this:

```
ELSE ORIGINAL_VALUE
```

Comment: It would, of course, be FAR better to alter the actual values once and then add the appropriate logic to prevent this sort of thing in the future. But that is surely shouting at the wind, so why not create either a view that does this or add a computed column? And simplify your life. Your first case branch can just be " when upper(dept) = 'HR' then 'Hr' else ..." You don't need to pull apart the 2 characters and then upper/lower each one and then string them back together.

Comment: To be clear, the point of the question is to find out whether a specific variable exists in a CASE statement to reference the original value. I'm not literally trying to accomplish this casing outcome. It's just test data to represent something analogous.

Comment: Simply or obscure too much often means no one really understands your goal. Terminology matters as well. The only variable in your script is the table. In addition, CASE is not a statement but an expression. It is unclear what "without repeating all the functions ..." actually means and the responses (and your own query) do exactly what you ask. If that is not useful, then obviously you need to provide more and better information. Perhaps by "variable" you mean the value of the expression in your first branch. A CTE or a derived table could be used.

Comment: And I stand by the first suggestions - use a view or a computed column. If this repetition is so taxing, then solve the problem once and never write this same code anywhere else.

Comment: @SMor Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `values` :

```
SELECT t.*, (CASE WHEN ORIGINAL_VALUE = 'Hr' THEN 'HR' ELSE ORIGINAL_VALUE 
             END)
FROM @table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (UPPER(SUBSTRING(dept, 1, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(dept, 2, LEN(dept) - 1)))
     ) tt(ORIGINAL_VALUE);
```